# Validate other user control from another

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I have one user control with a combobox (UC1) and I have another user control with one text box with two buttons (UC2).

I put one instance of UC2 on MainWindow. And I need to put 5 instances of UC1 on MainWindow too.

UC2 will allow user to browse for a text (CSV) file. After browsing the file, all column names will be populated in each Combobox (by using [MVVMFoundation](https://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/)'s Messenger class).

Then I put a validation on each Combobox view model to prevent user from selecting same column name twice. I can do individual validation by using IDataErrorInfo.
Eg: When ComboBox1 already selected ColA, if ComboBox2 selects ColA too, ComboBox2 will have validation error trigger and will show a red color border with tool tip.

But when I change ComboBox1 to ColB, ComboBox2 should clear of validation error (by normal logic). The problem is I don't know how to clear the error of ComboBox2 from ComboBox1 View Model.

What I have tried: 
1. I tried to send message to all registered combobox view model each time one combobx got validation check (but it will keep going into nested loop). So, I give up. 
2. (no idea of how can I achieve it).

Here is my code for Combobox View Model.

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get 
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "SelectedObject": result = CheckData(); break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    private string CheckData()
    {
        if (_menu == 1)
        {
            if (App.myExport1.chosenCols.ContainsValue(_selectedObject.ColIndex))
            {
                if (App.myExport1.chosenCols.ContainsKey(_colNo))
                    App.myExport1.chosenCols[_colNo] = _selectedObject.ColIndex;
                else
                    App.myExport1.chosenCols.Add(_colNo, _selectedObject.ColIndex);

                return "Column name already chosen!";
            }
            else
            {
                if (App.myExport1.chosenCols.ContainsKey(_colNo))
                    App.myExport1.chosenCols[_colNo] = _selectedObject.ColIndex;
                else
                    App.myExport1.chosenCols.Add(_colNo, _selectedObject.ColIndex);

                return null;
            }
        }
        else if (_menu == 2)
            return null;
        else if (_menu == 3)
            return null;
        else if (_menu == 4)
            return null;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Here is my ComboBox XAML code.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="cboCol"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Masters}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding ColIndex}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              DisplayMemberPath="ColName" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
```

Any suggestion/guide on how can I achieve it?
Please do not mind my above code if it is not in correct MVVM way though I said I'm using MVVM approach (I just start trying to use MVVM approach and still not familiar with it).

**Update**
After getting the feedback from "Jai", I understand and notice my wrong way of using single control in user control. Pardon my novice way of doing things. will consider the case is closed.

Comment: 1. You are probably splitting into too many subviews and viewmodels.
2. I'm not familiar with MVVMFoundation, but logically, you should have a property somewhere that holds all the values that has been used, and make validation check against the single ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Jai, yes my last solution will be this one. I have all my values in App.myExport1 Model class. I can do the validation check on it from MainViewModel and notify each view to show error (by show/hide DropShadow effect) But I'm not sure will it break MVVM way of doing things. So, I put on hold of this checking.

Comment: You should know you have oversplit into too many subviews/subviewmodels when you have a view with single UI component, with a single property in viewmodel to bind to. I would think that it's logically to group all the comboboxes into a single view/viewmodel. This way they can share a lot of things, and you won't need a messenger for every single thing.

Comment: @Jai, thanks for your suggestion. However, if I need to group them into one single user control, will it defeat the purpose of 'reuse'? Because as you can see from my above validation checking. I have different "Menu" option. each menu will represent different column selection so I can't put a fix number of combobox in one user control. so, I decided to create a single combobox user control. (Kindly correct me if my logic is wrong).

Comment: You are already reusing the component called "ComboBox". You are not creating this control by scratch already, are you? :)

Comment: @Jai, thanks for correcting my stubborn wrong logic. I see that I'm doing a wrong way, will change it accordingly.